# QT Creator - breakpoint not persistent for every build

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I'm trying to use QT Creator for an open-source project I downloaded from github. 
After some fuddling around I managed to get the project to compile in QT Creator and run in debug mode. 
However, I have an issue : strangely the breakpoints that I set are only available for that instance for the debug run for QT Creator. When I stop the debugging, and relaunch the debugging, the previously stated breakpoints are still there, but they are no longer valid. (meaning Qt Creator skips over them). I've verified that new breakpoints are still valid - it's the old ones that become invalid even though they are still listed.

I did not even update any code, just added breakpoints, hit debug and the old breakpoints became invalid even though they are still showing.

[image: QT Screen]

No sacarsm intended, but is this a "feature"? If so, how do I turn it off? 
If not a feature, what can I try?

It's very painful to re-add breakpoints every time I run a debug.

Using Mac OSX 10.9 here, Qt 5.2, with Qt Creator 3.0 for Mac.

Thanks.

EDIT : Some more info. I realised that whenever the breakpoint works, it has a tiny hour glass next to it, like in the picture. What does the hour glass mean? It could just be something dumb that I'm not doing.... 
[image]

Comment: are you editing your code and building again? or just relaunching .. pls specify

Comment: There is no QtCreator 5.2. That is the Qt version. Also, QT is Quick Time. Qt is `Q toolkit` as per tagwiki. Can you reproduce this issue on Windows or Linux? Are you just leaving debugging, and then entering again without any changes? Is it predictable? I.e. old breakpoints are never entered? What optimization level are you using for the build? Which toolchain, presumably llvm and clang?

Comment: Hi, I updated the description. I'm just adding breakpoints and the old breakpoints are disregarded in the 2nd run even though they are still showing. It is predictable. The old breakpoints are never entered. Where do I check the optimisation levels and toolchain? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried Windows/Linux. Will there be any difference?

Comment: @lppier: you can find the optimization level as -OX in the `make VERBOSE=1` output. It would make sense to try Windows and/or Linux to see if it is some Mac related issue, i.e. to pin it further down. You can check the toolchain in the settings.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I see this g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o ... continues  I guess the -o means no optimisation right? With no optimisations there shouldn't be such errors. :/

Comment: -o means output; `man gcc`. Look for capital `O`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I filed a bug with Qt Creator. For those interested pls check here. 
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11184